# Mongoose - Getting Uncaught RangeError when validating client-side document

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose for client-side model validation. I have the following code (this is a React component):

```
import templateSchema from '../../../shared/schemas/templateSchema.js';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TemplateDocSchema = new mongoose.Schema(templateSchema);

class TemplateEditInfo extends Component {
    ...
    saveStage(e) {
        var doc = new mongoose.Document({}, TemplateDocSchema);
        doc.validate(function(error) {

        });
    }
    ...
}
```

The `doc.validate` function is throwing the following error in the browser (latest Chrome):

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at
>   Object.exports.deprecate (eval at (app.js:866), :65:29) at
>   Promise.eval (eval at (app.js:866), :69:22) at Promise.eval (eval at
>   (app.js:866), :69:41) at Promise.eval (eval at (app.js:866), :69:41)
>   at Promise.eval (eval at (app.js:866), :69:41) at Promise.eval (eval
>   at (app.js:866), :69:41) at Promise.eval (eval at (app.js:866),
>   :69:41) at Promise.eval (eval at (app.js:866), :69:41) at Promise.eval
>   (eval at (app.js:866), :69:41) at Promise.eval (eval at (app.js:866),
>   :69:41)

The schema is as follows:

```
const templateSchema = {
    ref: {type: Number}
};
export default templateSchema;
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install a Promise package to solve this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
```